# How Do I add 2 text boxes with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, textfield

I need to add a number already from a textbox with a number from an array. 
currently getting NaN

```
       // textbox
 var totalScore = $("#totalPointsInt");
       // setting value
 $(totalScore).val(0);

 $(totalScore).val(parseFloat(totalScore.val) + 6);
```

Comment: what is total Score? show some code

Comment: need to show more code  but your posted code is not right   you need to use $(totalScore).val()   instead of totalScore.val

Answer (score 0):

as I said in comments you need to use `$(totalScore).val()` instead of `totalScore.val`

```
 $(totalScore).val(parseFloat($(totalScore).val()) + 6);
```

and while you use  `var totalScore = $("#totalPointsInt");` you can use `totalScore`directly instead of  `$(totalScore)`

```
// textbox
 var totalScore = $("#totalPointsInt");
 // setting value
 totalScore.val(0);
 totalScore.val(parseFloat(totalScore.val()) + 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
totalScore.val(parseFloat(totalScore.val()) + 6);
```

Comment: to make it a code .. select it and just hit  Ctrl+k :)